# Memory Error in Python when trying to convert large files to binary

Tags: python, binaries

I'm working on developing a program to generate a dictionary containing binaries of various files for a Minecraft modpack. Everything works smoothly when processing smaller files. However, when attempting to process larger files, such as the "Better End Reforked" mod which is 90MB in size, the program encounters a "Memory Error" and fails.

**This is my code:**

```
from os      import listdir
from os.path import abspath, splitext, basename, getsize, isfile, join, expandvars

def getBool(statement):
    return (True if statement else False)

def getFiles(path):
    list = []

    for file in listdir(path):
        filePath = join(path, file)
        if isfile(filePath):
            list.append((file, abspath(filePath)))
    
    return list

def getIdentity(path):
    name = basename(path)
    
    return {
        'name': name,
        'basename': splitext(name)[0], 
        'extension': splitext(name)[1],
        'realpath': abspath(expandvars(path)),
        'size': getsize(path)
    }

def fromFileToBinary(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            binary = file.read()
            return binary.hex()
    except IOError:
        return None


output = getIdentity('./output/bin.py')['realpath']

config       = 'C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/optional/config'
mod          = 'C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/optional/mods'
resourcepack = 'C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/optional/resourcepacks'
script       = 'C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/optional/scripts'

bool = getBool(config or mod or resourcepack or script)

def _bin(path = None, bool = True):
    dictionary = {}

    if path and bool:
        files = getFiles(path)
        
        for file in files:
            name, path = file
            dictionary[name] = fromFileToBinary(path)

    return dictionary

content = {
    'default': {
        'config':       _bin('C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/default/config', False),
        'mods':         _bin('C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/default/mods', False),
        'resourcepack': _bin('C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/default/resourcepacks', False),
        'script':       _bin('C:/Users/Berdy Alexei/Downloads/modpack/default/scripts', False)
    },
    'optional': (bool, {
        'config':       _bin(config),
        'mods':         _bin(mod),
        'resourcepack': _bin(resourcepack),
        'script':       _bin(script)
    })
}

with open(output, "w") as file:
    file.write('BIN = {}'.format(content))
```

**This is the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Folders\Archivos\Proyectos\InstallerCrafter\InstallerCrafter.py", line 75, in <module>
    file.write('BIN = {}'.format(content))
MemoryError
```

**These are the files I'm processing:**
[image]

Comment: please NEVER EVER use `list` as a variable name because it overshadows the typename `list`. Same goes for dict, int, float etc.

Comment: please post the whole memory error and show us where it encounters and how many files are there!?!?

Comment: Done, look again.

Comment: ah ok interesting that means you get a memory error when writing to a file, lemme see

Comment: What are you going to DO with this file?  Your code is converting the binary to a hex string, which doubles the size of the file.  You are formatting and reformatting and reformatting.  What's the use case?  Why not just store the binaries in a zip, for instance?

Comment: @NoBlockhit, no, they are getting a memory error in the `format` call, where they are formatting a dictionary with nested dictionaries with 200-megabyte strings.

Comment: whats gonna happen when you try to format your dict to json first and write that to the file?

Comment: It looks like that the file is very large compared to other files.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah true that might be the case, thats also why i suggested the thing above ^

Comment: And remember, it's not the 89MB that causes the problem.  You have that ENTIRE DIRECTORY, doubled in size, in a single dictionary.  That file happens to be the straw that broke the camel's back, but you have several hundred megabytes there.

Comment: @TimRoberts
As much research as I did I couldn't find information on how to create a "Files Installer" with Python, so I started experimenting and it turns out that I can put binaries in the variable in a .py file, import that .py file into another .py file which will process the binaries and will convert it back to files so that when I convert it to an executable, it leaves a single file with all the files I want to use. Making —in theory— an installer.
(A Modpacks Installer for Minecraft in this case)

Comment: Are you really telling me you didn't find pyinstaller, or py2exe, or cx_Freeze, or any of the other dozen packages for making Python installers?  Those basically create a zip file with your script and the data files it needs, which is a PRACTICAL solution to this.

Comment: @TimRoberts
I'm trying to make a very "Custom" program let's say so, plus I'm trying to understand how it works, I'd love to understand it.

More than practicality, I want to learn and understand this well. 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**My solution:**

```
def fromFileToBinary(path, size = 4):
    try:
        binary = ''

        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            while True:
                chunk = file.read(1024 *  size)

                if not chunk:
                    break

                binary += chunk.hex()
                del chunk

        return binary
    except IOError:
        return None
```

The disadvantage is that it takes a long time to generate the binary, however it can be improved by adding that, after a certain weight of the file, the function is executed in this way or not (See the "getIdentity" function above in the code).

Comment: Hard to believe that that makes a difference, since that's just a change in the part you didn't have trouble with.

Comment: @KellyBundy Although the error seemed to happen when the data was written to the file (in the last line of code), it turned out that the problem lay in how the files themselves were processed, especially those that were especially large.

Comment: What difference does that different processing make, though?

Comment: Right.  This can't possibly make a difference.  The result of this is exactly the same as `file.read().hex()`.

Answer (score 1):

A memory error means, that your program is running out of memory to store stuff. There is a workaround for that, which is storing binary data in smaller chunks.

Right now, the `_bin` method returns a HUGE variable, which your computer is just not ready to store, or do anything with for that matter. Instead of that, you can make the function read the files by let's say 1024 bytes (the `read()` function has a non-required argument which is the amount of bytes to read). And then, you could store said chunks in a list, which will be returned by the function. It would look something like this:

```
def fromFileToBinary(path, length):
    chunks = []
    try:
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            for i in range(length):
                binary = file.read(1024)
                chunks.append(binary.hex())
    except IOError:
        return None
    return chunks
```

Good thing you already handled the possibility of an `IOError`.

I also don't see the need for the `getBool` function. If you combine two or more objects with an `or` operator(s), the outcome will always be the type of boolean.

One more thing: naming convention. As NoBlockhit very accurately suggested, do not use variable names that would shadow already existing objects, like `bool` or `list`. And while the usage of `_` before a variable is most certainly okay, it is widely considered as a prefix for a variable in a class that isn't meant to be used outside the scope of said class.

Comment: It didn't work but you led me to the solution, thanks!

Comment: OK, you're right, but then what's the point?  If he's trying to create an installer, he'll need the whole file, not the first 1k bytes.

Comment: @TimRoberts I forgot to use a loop, fixed the solution now

Comment: Now we're back to where we started.  The `chunks` list will be just as large as the one-shot string read.  This cannot make a difference.